# How to not submit watermark text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, watermark

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.watermark').focus(function() {
        if (this.className == 'watermark')
        {
            this.className = '';
            this.reset = this.value;
            this.value = '';
        }
    });

    $('.watermark').blur(function() {
        if (this.value == '')
        {
            this.className = 'watermark';
            this.value = this.reset;
        }
    });
});
```

And it works fine, but when I submit my form the watermarks are submitted as data. Without modifying my php processing file, is it possible for watermarked text to be submitted as blank? What I mean is: if the textbox's class is 'watermark' submit a blank value for said textbox. I don't want to modify my php processing file but I do not mind using JQuery. Would the best solution be to capture the submit button's click event and quickly set textbox's with a watermark values to blank?

Comment: The best solution is not to do your watermarks by setting the *value* in the first place. Use `placeholder` or put a label underneath the (transparent) input.

Comment: Is placeholder fully supported? I couldn't get it to work. How would one put a label underneath the input? Edit: Apparently placeholder text only works with Firefox 3.7+ and I'm using 3.6 I'm going to upgrade but I probably shouldn't use it if it is this new.

Comment: To put a label under an input, use absolute positioning. Unpolished example: http://dorward.me.uk/tmp/label-work/example.html

Comment: for me watermark is handling this for chrome & firefox only IE is submitting the text

Answer (score 0):

this should work if i understood you correctly:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $(this).find('.watermark').each(function(){
        if(!this.reset)
             this.value = '';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `placeholder` attribute on your text input elements:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Text goes here" id="foo" />
```

Since this doesn't work in some older browsers, add an HTML5 `placeholder` attribute fallback script to your page (like [this](https://github.com/NV/placeholder.js) or [this](https://github.com/miketaylr/jQuery-html5-placeholder)).